# Keyboard and touchpad stop responding, since then I cannot boot

Tags: boot, keyboard, touchpad

My keyboard stopped responding, and my touchpad started responding only sporadically. By sporadically, I mean that if I draw a movement on the touchpad, the cursor will slowly follow it with glitches intermittently over the next few minutes. Since I couldn't get anything to restart, and keyboard shortcuts for the terminal etc. wouldn't function either, I forced a restart.

Since then I cannot boot into my Ubuntu partition. I've tried booting a previous version of the kernel (via the "Advanced Ubuntu Options" menu in grub), but this too just stays hanging at the Ubuntu start screen, before the login.

I can boot into my Windows 10 partition without any problem though, and keyboard ad mouse work perfectly there.

I can access the tty1 by selecting "upstart" in the "Advanced Ubuntu Options" in the grub, and clicking ctrl + alt + F1, and my keyboard works fine there. But once I'm in the shell, I have no idea what to do to diagnose the problem ...

Any idea what might be happening, or what I could do to diagnose it?

machine: Lenovo Thinkpad T460s
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS